# Overloaded Types Mismatch

Tags: c++

How does overloading work in C++?  I defined two overloaded functions one takes a float and the other takes an integer:

```
void myFunc(float a) { ... }
void myFunc(int a) { ... }
```

BUT I cannot use the int version whenever I try to pass an integer the compiler panic about an ambiguous call.  I only can use the float version.  Weird?

Thanks.

Comment: Please include code for how you're trying to call it.

Comment: Are you sure you're compiling as C++ and not C?

Comment: Nope, should work. Your question has no calling code and you did not specify a toolchain/platform, so only a psychic could solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

```
void f(int x)
{}
void f(float x)
{}

int main()
{
   int a = 2;
   f(a); //will unambiguously call f(int)
   f(3); //will unambiguously call f(int)
}
```

Why? Because `int->int` is an `exact match` which is always better than int->float, which is a `match with standard conversion`.
if this isn't the behaviour you're experiencing then your compiler is a bad compiler. In any case, overload resolution rules are a bit complicated. [This link](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/comphelp/v8v101/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.xlcpp8a.doc/language/ref/cplr315.htm) might help shed light on it

Answer (score 1):

> BUT I cannot use the int version
>   whenever I try to pass an integer the
>   compiler panic about an ambiguous
>   call.

No. It cannot complain that if you call it  as,

```
int i=10;
myFunc(i); //myFunc(int) gets called!
myFunc(1); //again myFunc(int) gets called!
```

See yourself here : http://ideone.com/RI33a

No ambiguity!

Comment: @Sonja: Could you show us the code? I suspect you're doing something wrong!

Answer (score 0):

You're probably unintentionally calling it with a `char` or `double` and the compiler can't figure out which version you actually want.